# Using "class of" in TDictionary?

Tags: delphi

Idea is simple - making TDictionary with class name to TComponent to use

```
for enum in vm.ClassNameToComponent do
 TLuaClassTemplate<enum.Value>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);
```

with enum instead of

```
TLuaClassTemplate<TButton>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);
TLuaClassTemplate<TPanel>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);
TLuaClassTemplate<TEdit>.RegisterClass(vm.LS, PrintGlobal, container, vm);
...
```

and to use class name taken from xml to work with generic based classes.
But there is problem:

```
TClassNameToComponentDict = TDictionary<string, TComponent>;
...
ClassNameToComponent: TClassNameToComponentDict;
...
  ClassNameToComponent := TClassNameToComponentDict.Create;
  ClassNameToComponent.Add('TButton', TButton);
  ClassNameToComponent.Add('TPanel', TPanel);
  ClassNameToComponent.Add('TEdit', TEdit);
...
```

error "Incompatible types 'TComponent' and 'class of TButton'".
How to use "class of" like TButton etc as generic value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type you have used

```
TDictionary<string, TComponent>
```

represents a mapping from a string to an **instance** of a class. But you want a mapping from a string to the **class**. So you need:

```
TDictionary<string, TComponentClass>
```

where

```
TComponentClass = class of TComponent
```

Note that you do not need to declare `TComponentClass` since it is already declared in the `Classes` unit.